# Python introspect: get all declared identifiers and their types

Tags: python, introspection

In any particular Python interpreter session, I wish I could build a function
`full_introspect` whose output would be such a tree structure:

```
{'identifier': {'type': type, 'substructure': {'subidentifier': {'type': etc..} ..}}, ...}
```

The meaning of such a structure would be:

- `identifier` actually refers to an object of type `type`. So if I type
  `identifier` in the interpreter now, I will get that object.
- `identifier.subidentifier` actually refers to an object of type `etc`. So if I
  type `identifier.subidentifier` in the interpreter now, I will get that
  object (class/object member, package method, *etc*.)

Is it possible without falling in endless loops? (I guess some package aliases might introduce cycles in the 'tree"). Which tools would I need? Does this already exist so I don't need to reinvent wheel?

Comment: `locals()`, `globals()`, `dir(object)` and `type(object)`. Have fun!

Comment: @KlausD. Glad it sounds so simple :) Will I not get into trouble with packages? Shall I reinvent the wheel?

Comment: It's certainly possible, though non-trivial because of circular/recursive references. The pickle module does this in order to serialize objects. You may want to look into the internals of https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.Pickler , possibly subclassing it.

Comment: @BingsF this sounds much more closer from what I expected, especially concerning circular references. I'll have a look into this pickler, cheers ;)